# Como resaltar item de ListView en Android

Tags: android

Tengo un `Listview` que muestra dispositivos Bluetooth disponibles y quisiera que de todos ellos el que está `seleccionado por defecto o emparejado` se muestre con un `distintivo de color` al costado como el de la figura, alguien me puede decir como hacerlo.

Aqui mi codigo:

```
 @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(getActivity(), 0, listItems) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
            BluetoothDevice device = listItems.get(position);
            if (view == null)
                view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.device_list_item, parent, false);
            TextView text1 = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            TextView text2 = view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            text1.setText(device.getName());
            text2.setText(device.getAddress());
            return view;
        }
    };
}
```

Así es como quiero que se muestre:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en tu listItem hay alguna propiedad por la cual se pueda saber si esta emparejado o no?

Comment: `Igmer Rodriguez`, tengo un flag que me indica si esta conectado o no

Comment: Y tienes un adaptador personalizado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el layout de cada item puede agregarle una etiqueta `<View>`con el color que deseas y le agregas la propiedad `<android:visibility="gone">`. Ahora dentro de tu adapter puedes jugar con la visibilidad, si esta conectado puedes cambiar la propiedad `View.VISIBLE` y si no lo esta le agregas `View.GONE`.

Enlace de referencia :
https://codeday.me/es/qa/20190304/273132.html

Comment: `rguzman`, yo no quiero que toda la fila tenga esa propiedad, solo al borde izquierdo como aparece en la imagen al inicio

Comment: Hola @W1ll si eso mismo, todas las filas tendrán el view pero tu puedes controlar donde se puede mostrar y donde no.

Comment: El rectángulo de color verde que aparece al borde izquierdo de la columna es una propiedad o es una imagen?

Comment: Según la imagen que adjuntaste es una imagen. Porque tu estas construyendo la lista y tu también deberías de agregarle todas la propiedades que quieres a cada item de tu vista, en este caso el rectángulo verde que puede ser un `<view>`.